# Alternative for a Nested Aggregate as a group filter SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that needs to get only the top 10 of that category and sort it from highest value to lowest having this kind of expression:

```
=Sum(Sum(Fields!Measure.Value, "RowGroup1"), "RowGroup2")
```

But the problem is, the only filter that SSRS accepts is the simple aggregate:

```
=Sum(Fields!Measure.Value)
```

Not using the nested aggregate will give the wrong top 10.

Another thing, the client is using Analysis Services as the connection for the report so I cannot tweak the dataset by using a query. The fix should be inside SSRS. Is there anyway to do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using **Top N** filter from the chart properties. You might want to sort the values before using the filter.

Comment: Yup, that's what I am using right now. But I can't have the Top N of the said nested aggregate. That's the problem. What I can only have right now is getting the Top N of Sum(Fields!Measure.Value) but not Sum(Sum(Fields!Measure.Value, "RowGroup1"), "RowGroup2") and that's why it's wrong.